# N-API - complex objects as arguments to native

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

Longtime user of SO but first time asking a question.

I currently have a javascript addon that can call into the native C++ code. What I'm having problems with is passing in a 'complex' javascript object and being able to perform operations on the N-API side, such as calling back to javascript callbacks. My code included as example:

addon.js:

```
const native = require('bindings')('addon').native

const client = {  

  loadState: (cb) => {

  },
  onObjCreate: () => { // <== This is where I'm trying to callback
    console.log('returned from native')
  },
  onOperationComplete: (result, someId) => {

  },
  saveState: (state, cb) => {

  },
  loadURL: (url, headers, content, contentType, method, cb) => {
    console.log('load URL')
  }
}

const obj = new native(client)
obj.createObj()
```

addon.cc:

```
#include "node_obj.h"

napi_value Init(napi_env env, napi_value exports) {
  return NodeObj::Init(env, exports);
}

NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)
// NAPI_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

node_obj.cc

```
#define NAPI_CALL(call) \
do { \
  napi_status status = call; \
  if (status != napi_ok) { \
    const napi_extended_error_info* result; \
    napi_status errStatus = napi_get_last_error_info(env, &result); \
    napi_throw_error(env, NULL, result->error_message); \
    return nullptr; \
  } \
} while (0)

#define DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD(name, func)                          \
  { name, 0, func, 0, 0, 0, napi_default, 0 }

napi_ref NodeObj::constructor;

NodeObj::NodeObj(Client* value) 
  :  value_(value), env_(nullptr), wrapper_(nullptr) {}

NodeObj::~NodeObj() { napi_delete_reference(env_, wrapper_); }

void NodeObj::Destructor(napi_env env, void* nativeObject, void*) {
  reinterpret_cast<NodeObj*>(nativeObject)->~NodeObj();
}

napi_value NodeObj::CreateObj(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info) {
  std::cout << "creating obj" << std::endl;
  napi_value global, on_obj_created_callback, jsthis;
  NAPI_CALL(napi_get_global(env, &global));
  void* data;

  NAPI_CALL(napi_get_cb_info(env, info, NULL, NULL, &jsthis, &data));
  std::cout << "creating obj2" << std::endl;

  // Doesn't get past this below, don't think global is the correct 
  // object to get from but can't find a way to bring in other objects
  NAPI_CALL(napi_get_named_property(env, global, "onObjCreate", &on_obj_created_callback));     
  std::cout << "creating obj3" << std::endl;

  NAPI_CALL(napi_call_function(env, global, on_obj_created_callback, 0, NULL, NULL));
  std::cout << "creating obj4" << std::endl;

  return NULL;
}

napi_value NodeObj::Init(napi_env env, napi_value exports) {
  napi_property_descriptor properties[] = {

    DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD("createObj", CreateObj)
  };
  napi_value cons;
  NAPI_CALL(napi_define_class(env, "native", NAPI_AUTO_LENGTH, New, nullptr, 2, properties, &cons));
  NAPI_CALL(napi_create_reference(env, cons, 1, &constructor));
  NAPI_CALL(napi_set_named_property(env, exports, "native", cons));

  return exports;
}
```

//New: hacky right now as I try different things

```
napi_value NodeObj::New(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info) {
  napi_value target;
  NAPI_CALL(napi_get_new_target(env, info, &target));
  bool is_constructor = target != nullptr;

  // Invoked as `new Class(...)`
  if (is_constructor) {
    size_t argc = 1;
    napi_value args[1];
    NAPI_CALL(napi_get_cb_info(env, info, &argc, args, nullptr, nullptr));

    Client* client;
    napi_valuetype valuetype;
    NAPI_CALL(napi_unwrap(env, args[0], reinterpret_cast<void**>(&client)));
    NAPI_CALL(napi_typeof(env, args[0], &valuetype));
    if (valuetype != napi_undefined) {
      NAPI_CALL(napi_get_prototype(env, args[0], &client));
    }

    NodeObj* nodeObj = new NodeObj(reinterpret_cast<Client*>(client));
    nodeObj->env_ = env;
    NAPI_CALL(napi_wrap(env, jsthis, reinterpret_cast<void*>(nodeObj), NodeObj::Destructor, nullptr, &nodeObj->wrapper_));
    return jsthis;
........
```

From ::New, I want to be able to bring in the js arg (`client` in `const obj = new native(client)`) on the native side and use it to callback to it's js functions. Is this possible and what would be the best way to go about doing this?